# How do I force Watch to record heart rate during a workout?

Tags: apple-watch, health-kit

When I record a workout using Watch, regardless of what app I use, including Apple's own Workout app, Watch almost always fails to capture the first 5-30 minutes of heart rate data. This (almost) only happens at the start of a workout, and it happens with 80-90% of workouts, regardless of the kind (cycling, walking, hiking, running, weights, pilates, etc.)

How do I force Watch to record heart rate during a workout?

Answer (score 0):

There are no settings for when to enable the use of the Heart Rate monitor on a Workout, neither in the Settings app on the Watch itself for Workouts, nor on the iPhone's Apple Watch app. Apple's Apple Watch User's Guide ( https://support.apple.com/guide/watch/start-a-workout-on-apple-watch-apd673ee7114/9.0/watchos/9.0 ) similarly states that you can simply "Raise your wrist to see your […], […] heart rate.", implying that you don't have to do anything, it'll just be there.

There are three possibilities I see here:

1. A software bug.
2. A hardware failure causing sensor failure, or;
3. An impairment causing sensor failure. The only detail I've ever known for impeding the sensor is a tattoo. I don't know if other skin conditions would cause it.

Does the Heart Rate app return your heart rate within ~3 seconds of opening it? Do you have background heart rate measurements on and do they update at a steady rate? Does the ECG feature work?

Comment: I'm wagering that you'll be making a trip to an Apple Store, or at least the Watch will be, for repair, soon.

Comment: I've spoken with other folks and this appears to be common. Watch just often fails to pick up the start of a workout. There's not much that can be done.